# Hierarchy in Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, directory

Help! My launcher is full! And scrolling through the icons is so painfully slow!

Is there any possibility to apply a hierarchy in the launcher? Some folder-like icon where you can put in a bunch of launcher icons? And when you click on it, they will be shown. So you can start an app in the launcher with two clicks instead of one and you don't have to scroll all the way down every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drawers for it. It creates a drwaer (like a folder) in the launcher and you can drag and drop several other icons in it.

Install it like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

And then when you start the application, you can choose what to name it and then it will be added to the Launcher. Drag and drop your favourites in it.

You can refer to my tutorial on Make Tech Easier for more details: http://maketecheasier.com/group-apps-together-in-unity-launcher/2012/08/10